# Fridge won't cool. Freon pressure doing crazy things

Tags: refrigerator

Hello all  I am new to site. So if I post to the wrong spot I'm apologizing in advance. I just bought a 48" thermidor used. From all my research I've done this fridge cost about 9k new. It's about 4yrs old now. I bought it for $400 . When I got it the compressor was unplugged. The previous owner said the compressor was bad. So I assumed that a tech came in and unplugged the compressor to make a sale. I plugged it back in and put my gauges on it. Low side was -28 hi side was about 50. So paperwork says that freon pressure should be , low side 3 to 7 and hi side should be 90 +/- 25 @70degress. I can get the hi side to the correct number but the low side is really low. Like -27 or 25. So I out more freon in. To get the low side to come up we re looking at a head pressure if about 300. I'm thinking blockage. But where? I have alot of experience in residential heat and a/c and automotive. But refrigeration not so much. So what do ya think?Where should I be looking?  Because this thing is so expensive I would really like to get it going. We just bought a house and the opening for the fridge is 48". No way I can buy a new one.
Thanks a million in advance

Comment: Perhaps the tech who noted the compressor was bad was not as corrupt as you assumed. :-)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing we won't be able to help you on this one; sorry. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hvactalk would be a better location if you have a license. What type Freon? Trying to figure -28 to me it looks like a suction valve was closed some place, if you are at -28 don’t run it for long being close to a vacuum their will be little heat transfer and you can smoke your windings.

Comment: Sealed units have no user serviceable parts inside. There's one on eBay with a leak and a "new compressor" for ~$1000. Or sell yours and make $600 (GL). There's another one for ~$700, same boat as yours. If new ones are $9k and *almost-working* ones are $1000... that's too many red flags for me. Model number? How much is a compressor?

Comment: Nine thousand dollar fridges are for people who don't sign their own checks... It'd be cheaper, now and in the long run, to re-do the cabinetry for standard size fridges.